# how do i store a return value in the format 2014-06-15 19:51:37 to a datetime variable in python?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have done some researching and I believe I am supposed to use the datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp() method but I do not know exactly how to change a datetime in format 2014-06-15 19:51:37 to a variable usable in python where i can add and subtract and compare the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `datetime.datetime.strptime`.  Specifically, the timeformat you will be using is 
`'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

e.g:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date_str = '2014-06-15 19:51:37'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 15, 19, 51, 37)
```

Comment: Ok so how do I add say add 2 hours to a datetime object?
edit: nevermind I found it thanks!